# jQuery UI modal dialog form show success dialog after post action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm trying to use jQuery UI Dialog Modal Form with Modal Message after the $.post action as a dialog for Successful submitting message.

so here is the code:

```
    if ( bValid ) {
         $.post("contact.php", $("#contact").serialize());
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
         Ok: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
        }
       });
      }
    },
```

everything works fine except the dialog-message div is readable on the page and disappears only when $( "#dialog-message" ) called in modal window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post action is asynchronous you need to call the dialog inside a callback function:

```
$.post("contact.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(){//callback function
         $("#dialog-message").dialog({
             modal: true,
             buttons: {
                 Ok: function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
         });
});
```